# Unable to pull through API to react frontend with

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I am struggling to pull through the api to the front end. I completed it successfully with
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ Just mapped out the arrays. i am struggling however to pull through this seperate api I wanted to use

https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ts=redant&hash=140e85a50884cef76d614f6dacada288

the erro is..
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')"

so clearly it isnt actually able to get hold of results

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    list: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?apikey=3cb62d086d5debdeea139095cbb07fe4&ts=redant&hash=140e85a50884cef76d614f6dacada288')
    .then (response =>  response.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({list:users}))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
  
    {
      this.state.list.data.results.map(result => 
      <h1 key={result.id}>{result.urls}</h1>
      )
    }

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: First of all you set `this.state.list` as an empty array but in `render()` you try to access `this.state.list.data`. An [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) doesn't have an attribute `data` so that makes no sense. Also both `fetch` and `setState` are async. When your component first renders `this.state.list` will be an empty list and the request will only be started **after** the component mounted and rendered the first time.

Comment: Also do not include API secrets in a publicly accessible question on SO. I removed it for you. If this is a sensitive secret consider it compromised from now on and change it asap.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')` in your code means that `this.state.list.data` returns as `undefined`. This means that you'll need to focus on your state property `list` to ensure that it has a `data` property. As we see in your constructor, `data` is initialized to an empty array which does not contain the `data` property.
Something we can do to prevent the error is to surround your code with an undefined check:

```
if (this.state.list.data != undefined) {
   this.state.list.data.results.map(result => 
      <h1 key={result.id}>{result.urls}</h1>
   )
}
```

At this point, though, we don't know if your API call is returning good data or not since your program throws the error before that (since the fetch and setState are asynchronous), so the code above mainly addresses the error that you're getting rather than focusing on the "pull through the api to the front end" portion of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do inside your then part after fetching the results

```
this.setState({list:users.data.results}
```

And inside the map function, do the following:

```
this.state.list.map(result => 
  <h1 key={result.id}>{result.urls}</h1>
```

You are getting an error because List is initially empty it doesn't have any `key` called as `results`, once you fetch the result only then can you loop through your result.

Another solution would be to simply add a loader, you can control that via state as well.